# Finding critical numbers

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble finding critical numbers, specifically finding the roots or zeroes of a function. Especially when it involves a fraction.

For example right now I have 
$$\begin{align*}
f(x) &= x^2 - x - \ln x\\
f' (x) &= 2x - 1 - \frac {1}{x}\\
f' (x) &= 2x - 1 - \frac {1}{x} = 0\\
f' (x) &= 2x  - \frac {1}{x} = 1\\
f' (x) &= 2x^2  - 1 = x.
\end{align*}$$
Here I multiplied by $x$ on both sides which seems to be okay to do but it does not give me the same answer as if I were to plug in a number, for example 11, into 
$$
\begin{align*}
f' (x) &= 2x - 1 - \frac {1}{x} = 0\\
f' (x) &= 2x^2  -x - 1 = 0\\
\end{align*}$$

I know these are basic math concepts I should have mastered by now but I can't figure this out. Shouldn't both those function be equal to eachother?

Comment: You're supposed to find the roots of $2x^2-x-1=0$; you could use either the quadratic formula or remember how to factor quadratic polynomials like this...

Comment: Why is what I am doing wrong though? I did everything right according to math.

Comment: Note: the third line in your list of equations is incorect. It is true that $2x-1-\frac{1}{x}=0$ is equivalent to $2x-\frac{1}{x}=1$, but $2x-\frac{1}{x}$ is **not** equal to $f'(x)$ anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fine down to $2x-1-\frac 1x=0$ and multiplying by $x$ is fine, too (you know $x \ne 0$ as it is not in the domain of the logarithm), but moving the $1$ to the other side was wasted effort.  Now you have $2x^2-x-1=0$ which you can either factor as $(2x+1)(x-1)=0$ or use the quadratic formula to get the same result.  As the domain of the logarithm is $x\gt 0$, the only critical point is $x=1$

Comment: Is it wrong to factor as $(2x+1)(x-1)$?

Comment: @Jordan:  not at all.  You want the roots of the polynomial.  As I said, you get the same answer either way, but need to exclude the root $x= \frac {-1}2$ as it is not in the domain of the original function.